# How to set a flag in my Single Page Application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

In my Single Page Application (modeled after Hot Towel which durandal.js, knockout.js, and require.js), I am trying to set a flag (HasAccess) to indicate if a user has authenticated or not. I am doing this in a file called shell.js.  That file is ran in every view (index.vbhtml references main.js, main.js sets the app root as shell view, which runs the shell.js in every view).  Here is the shell.js viewmodel code-

```
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/logger', 'services/SecurityDataService'],
        function (system, router, logger, SecurityDataService) {

            var HasAccess = ko.observable(HasAccess);

            var vm = {
                activate: activate,
                router: router
            };
        return vm;

        function UserHasAccess() {
                return SecurityDataService.getHasAccess(HasAccess);
        }

        function activate() {
                return boot();
        }

        function boot() {
                HasAccess = SecurityDataService.getHasAccess();
                if HasAccess == "True") {
                    router.mapNav('home');
                    router.mapNav('CAApproval');

                    log('LucasNet Loaded!', null, true);


                return router.activate('home');
                }
                else {
                    router.map([
                        { url: 'AccessDenied', moduleId: 'viewmodels/AccessDenied', name: 'AccessDenied', visible: false }
                    ]);


                        return router.activate('AccessDenied'); // should show details page of a particular folder
                    log('Access Denied!', null, true);
                }
        }

        function log(msg, data, showToast) {
                logger.log(msg, data, system.getModuleId(shell), showToast);
        }
    });
```

The file containing the getHasAccess is in a dataservice file called SecurityDataService.js.  That code is-

```
define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system'],
        function (logger, system) {
            var SecurityModel = function (HasAccess) {
                var self = this;
                self.HasAccess = ko.observable(HasAccess);
        };


        var getHasAccess = function (strHasAccess) {
                $.getJSON('/api/security', function (data) {

                    strHasAccess = "";
                    if (typeof (data) == "string") {
                            strHasAccess = data;
                    } else {
                            strHasAccess = "False";
                    }

                    return strHasAccess;
                });
        }


        var dataservice = {
                getHasAccess: getHasAccess
        };

        return dataservice;

    });
```

EDIT  ADDED MY CONTROLLER CODE

```
Public Class SecurityController
    Inherits ApiController

        ' GET api/security
    Public Function GetValues()
            Dim boolHasAccess As String = ""
            Try

                    Dim objUser As LucasEntities.Business.IEF_WUserID = New LucasEntities.Business.EF_WUserID



                    Dim objSecurity As New LucasEntities.Business.EF_Security

                    boolHasAccess = objSecurity.GetUserPermissionsJSON(Utilities.GetLogin(), "CAAPPRV")

            Catch ex As Exception
                    Dim shouldRethrow As Boolean =     ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Policy")
                    If shouldRethrow Then
                        Throw
                    End If
            End Try



            Return boolHasAccess

        End Function
End Class



    Return boolHasAccess

End Function
```

The problem I have is that goes into the else statement in the boot method, and then it runs the call to getHasAccess in SecurityDataService.js (after the AccessDenied view is activated).

How can i first set the HasAccess flag before determining which view to display (home view if authenticated, AccessDenied view if not authenticated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getHasAccess` is making a $.getJSON call, so you'd probably need to wrap that via '$.when()`to make sure that`getHasAccess` is resolved before moving on.

Something along the line.

```
function boot() {
  return  $.when(SecurityDataService.getHasAccess()).then(function(HasAccess){

        if (HasAccess == "True") {
            router.mapNav('home');
            router.mapNav('CAApproval');

            log('LucasNet Loaded!', null, true);


        return router.activate('home');
        }
        else {
            router.map([
                { url: 'AccessDenied', moduleId: 'viewmodels/AccessDenied', name: 'AccessDenied', visible: false }
            ]);


                return router.activate('AccessDenied'); // should show details page of a particular folder
            log('Access Denied!', null, true);
        }
    };

}
```

BTW At them moment `var HasAccess = ko.observable(HasAccess);` at the top of `shell.js` is defined as observable, but than in boot() it's been handled as a normal variable `HasAccess = SecurityDataService.getHasAccess();`

Comment: Thanks RainerAtSpirit.  How should HasAccess be declared then if I want to use it as a normal variable?

Comment: `var HasAccess = '';` as you expect it to hold `strHasAccess`. Once you implemented the changes to `boot` you might consider getting rid of it completely as I don't see it anywhere else used in the example.

Comment: $.when(SecurityDataService.getHasAccess()).then(function (HasAccess) { takes it to         var getHasAccess = function (HasAccessObservable) {
            $.getJSON('/api/security', function (data) {
                strHasAccess = "";
                if (typeof (data) == "string") {
                    strHasAccess = data;
                } else {
                    strHasAccess = "False";
                }
 
                return strHasAccess;
            });
        }  BUT  it does not hit the code within the getJSON call until later after the accessdenied view is displayed.  Ideas?

Comment: I also added my web api controller code. Perhaps the problem is there?  See edit

Comment: Also note that HasAccess comes back as undefined.

Comment: Test the endpoint standalone. My assumption is that the endpoint simply never returns `'True'` and that's what you're testing against.

In `getHasAccess` return the JSON call e.g. `return $.getJSON('/api/security', function (data) {...`. Set a breakpoint in `boot` at  `if (HasAccess == "True") {` and check the value.

Comment: Looks like the $.getJSON call being nested inside of var getHasAccess = function (strHasAccess) { is the problem.  I created a deferred jquery call using the getjson call, so the code became as $.when($.getJSON('/api/security', function(data) {.   The deferred part became- .then(function (HasAccess) {.  By doing that, it no longer skips over the code under the getjson call, and populates the hasaccess flag as intended.  Thanks RainerAtSpirit.